# Why is the nonzero eigenvalue of $xx^T-yy^T$ negative when $y=\alpha x$ and $\alpha>1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assuming $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$, please tell me why the nonzero eigenvalue of $A=xx^T-yy^T$ is always negative if $y=\alpha x$ and $\alpha>1$, based on algebra principles?

It is possible to show $A=(1-\alpha^2)xx^\top$ and if $xx^T$ is psd then A is negative semidefinite and problem solved. But i like to know the key principle which make $xx^T$ a psd (a symmetric matrix with positive non-zero eigenvalues) in this situation.

Comment: Considering your assumptions, is $1-\alpha^2$ positive or negative?

Comment: Did you try simply inserting $y$?

Comment: "a symmetric matrix with positive non-zero eigenvalues" - doesn't seem right, a positive semidefinite matrix can be singular; it is a *positive definite* matrix that is guaranteed to have nonzero eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $xx^T$ is positive semi-definite "by definition" because for any $z$ we have
$$z^T (xx^T) z = (x^Tz)^T(x^Tz) = \|x^Tz\|\geq0.$$

Since your matrix is $(1-\alpha^2)xx^T$ and $\alpha>1$, it is negative semi-definite, whence all eigenvalues are negative or zero.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$xx^\top-yy^ \top=(1-\alpha^2)xx^\top,$$
thus the question reduces to showing that $xx^\top$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: yes i already got to that obvious point, but my problem is why $xx^T$ is a psd matrix based on what principle?

Comment: Yes, what else do you want to show?

Comment: @Bob, "yes i already got to that obvious point" - then why did you not say so in your question so that we aren't wasting your time and ours?

Comment: @J.M. I meant no offense, just tried to make clear where is my problem! But anyway, you made a fair point!

Comment: Okay, and what definition of "positive semidefinite" is your class using, @Bob?